# How to configure or enable Analytics in Self hosted Parse Server and Dashboard

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, parse-server, parse-dashboard

I am using self hosted Parse server with parse dashboard, My question is how to configure / Integrate or enable Parse Analytics.
Means how to enable or configure Analytics Adopters in Parse Server and enable Analytics widget in Parse Dashboard.
I do not want to use parse alternative analytics if its possible.
Any Help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is there no one GURU to help on this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today (August 2018) it looks like Analytics with Parse Server is not supported.

https://docs.parseplatform.org/parse-server/guide/#analytics

It also seems that there are no plans to implement the Analytics feature in the open-source Parse Server.

https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues/182

You could create your own "Class" and store whatever information you want in it, but you'd also need to build your own system for viewing that data.